# Passwordless ssh on cloudera hadoop

Tags: ssh, hadoop

I am using cdh4 on ec2. On the master node I don't see any keys pre-built and in fact passwordless ssh from master to hadoop slave node(s) does not work out-of-the-box.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-196-blah-blah ~]$ ping ip-10-32-6-133.ec2.internal
PING ip-10-32-blah-133.blah.internal (10.32.6.133) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ip-10-32-blah-blah.ec2.internal (10.32.6.133): icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=0.487 ms
64 bytes from ip-10-32-blah-blah.ec2.internal (10.32.6.133): icmp_seq=2 ttl=61 time=0.445 ms
```

But ssh does not do as well:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-196-blah-blah ~]$ ssh ec2-user@ip-10-32-blah-blah.ec2.internal
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Let's take a look if any ssh keys were prebuilt as part of cdh4 install:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-196-blah-blah ~]$ ls -lrta ~/.ssh
total 16
-rw-------  1 ec2-user ec2-user  402 Apr 14 20:03 authorized_keys
drwx------  2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 May 25 19:12 .
-rw-r--r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user 1271 May 25 19:12 known_hosts
drwx------. 9 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 May 25 19:15 ..
```

Nope..

What is the way to ssh to the slaves from the master given passwordless ssh is not working? Are we supposed to log on as ec2-user with a password? What is that password by default?

Answer (score 0):

Did you attempt to manually generate the public/private key-pair using **ssh-keygen** ?

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: Given the above scenario how would one even log on to the slave to run ssh-keygen?